# Vertices of a parallelogram inside of a quadrilateral using vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $E$ and $F$ be the midpoints of the sides $AB$ and $CD$ of a quadrilateral $ABCD$. Prove that the midpoints of segments $AF$, $BF$, $CE$, and $DE$ are vertices of a parallelogram.[image]
This is what I have so far but I don't know if it's right or where to go with it.

Comment: Mention if $AD||BC$.

Comment: Please show your effort. Assume position vectors of the vertices of the quadrilateral are $a, b, c, d$ then you can easily find position vectors of the vertices of $GHIJ$. Then showing that the sides are parallel is just finding direction vectors.

Comment: @RAHUL the problem does not mention that AD is parallel to BC it just says ABCD is a quadrilateral

Comment: I also need to use vectors

Comment: You need at least three vectors to describe the shape of a general quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach the problem.  We want to prove that segments GH and JI are parallel and of the same length, likewise, for the other 2 sides. If there were a vector, $v=H-G$ and another vector $v_1=I-J$,  then if they turned out to be the same vector, by algebra, then we could say they were both parallel and of the same length.  That is the game plan.
Define midpoint $$E=\frac{A+B}{2}$$
Define midpoint $$F=\frac{C+D}{2}$$
Define midpoint $$G=\frac{A+F}{2}$$
Define midpoint $$H=\frac{D+E}{2}$$
Now substitute into $v$ and $v_1$

$$v=H-G=\frac{D+E}{2}-\frac{A+F}{2}$$
and continue by substituting for $E$ and $F$
$$v=\frac{D+\frac{A+B}{2}}{2}-\frac{A+\frac{C+D}{2}}{2}$$
Now algebraically untangle this nonsense to get
$$v=-\frac{1}{4}A+\frac{1}{4}B-\frac{1}{4}C+\frac{1}{4}D$$

---

Next we will define the 2 midpoints that we don't have yet.
Define midpoint $$I=\frac{B+F}{2}$$
Define midpoint $$J=\frac{E+C}{2}$$
Now substitutions for $I$ and $J$
$$v_1=I-J=\frac{B+F}{2}-\frac{E+C}{2}$$
Next more substitutions for $E$ and $F$, defined above:
$$v_1=\frac{B+\frac{C+D}{2}}{2}-\frac{C+\frac{A+B}{2}}{2}$$
Once again do the algebra untangle:
$$v_1=-\frac{1}{4}A+\frac{1}{4}B-\frac{1}{4}C+\frac{1}{4}D$$
See that $v$=$v_1$.
Now you can do the same idea with the other 2 sides and conclude that you have a parallelogram.